# Unable to save multiple contacts by different buttons

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to fetch contacts from my phonebook and save the name and number of a contact. I want to save 3 contacts. For which, 3 EditTexts And respective buttons are there. On button click user is directed to contacts where user can select desired contact. But, I am unable to implement Contact-fetch function for all 3 Edit Texts.
When i implement this with one contact only, code works fine. But, how can this be implemented in the case of multiple contacts.
Contact.java

```
    package com.kamal.sos10;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Contact extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText msg,editText2,editText3,editText4;
Button con1,con2,con3;
static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

    msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    con1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.con1);
    con2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.con2);
    con3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.con3);

    con1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.putExtra("extra_text1", "1");
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(Contact.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        }
    });

    con2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.putExtra("extra_text2", "2");
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(Contact.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        }
    });

    con3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.putExtra("extra_text3", "3");
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(Contact.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        }
    });


}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String text1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_text1");
    Toast.makeText(Contact.this,text1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_OK) {
            contactPicked(data);
        }
    }
}

private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    try {
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cur = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the contact ID
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        // column index of the contact name
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        // column index of the phone number
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{id}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
            String phone = pCur.getString(
                    pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll(" ", "");
            /*String text1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_text1");
             Toast.makeText(Contact.this,text1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             if (text1.equals("1")) {
               editText2.setText(phone);
            }
            String text2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_text2");
            if (text2 == "2") {
              editText3.setText(phone);
            }
            String text3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_text3");
            if (text3 == "3") {
             editText4.setText(phone);
        */}


            pCur.close();
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used PICK_CONTACT = 1 for all three occurrences of startActivityForResult

```
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Give different value for each occurrence of startActivityForResult like below:

```
con1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.putExtra("extra_text", "1");
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(Contact.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }
});

con2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.putExtra("extra_text", "2");
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(Contact.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    }
});

con3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.putExtra("extra_text", "3");
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(Contact.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        }
    }
});
```

Now in your onActivityResult change the below code:

```
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_OK) {
        contactPicked(data);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
if (requestCode == 1 || requestCode == 2 || requestCode == 3) {
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_OK) {
        contactPicked(data);
    }
}
```

Now to print phone number in edittext box add the below code to  contactPicked(Intent data):

```
String text = data.getStringExtra("extra_text").toString();
if (text.equals("1")) {
           editText2.setText(phone);
}           
else if (text == "2") {
          editText3.setText(phone);
}            
else (text == "3") {
         editText4.setText(phone);
}
```

Comment: How to set phone no fetched from phonebook in the respective edittext ? Like i want to set edittext2 with contact fetched by using con1 and so on

Comment: @KamalKumar Check the latest edit, please accept the answer if this solved your problem :)